# insert if not exists in HQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hibernate, hql

I am trying to write a query in HQL which can insert a record if it does not exists (with same name) so that there is no duplicate insertion when done from multiple threads.

```
String hql = "INSERT INTO employee(emp_id, emp_name)"
        + " SELECT '100001' , 'John' " FROM employee
        + " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from employee WHERE emp_name  = 'John')";
```

However, the record is not inserted. I suspect this is because the table is empty and the subquery returns 0 records despite the NOT EXISTS clause.

Note - '100001' , 'John' & will programmatically be replaced in the actual query string.

Comment: You can define `emp_name` as UNIQUE and then just use `INSERT IGNORE`

Comment: INSERT IGNORE worked, wondering if there is a way to avoid direct query on the table bypassing the entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are selecting constant values from an empty table. Thus you are selecting and inserting zero rows. Note that if the table had two rows but neither of them have `emp_name  = 'John'`, you would insert two rows. So you should select from a table with exactly one row:

```
INSERT INTO employee(emp_id, emp_name)
SELECT '100001' , 'John' 
FROM (select 1) as dummy -- derived table with one row
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from employee WHERE emp_name  = 'John')
```

Instead of `(select 1) as dummy` you can also use `dual` im MySQL.

As I wrote in the comment you can also define the `emp_name` column as UNIQUE and then just use `INSERT IGNORE`.

Answer (score 1):

**Task**: We need to add row with unique `someId`.
But ignore if `someId` is not unique.

**Exists data** (postgresql):

```
+------------------------------+
|            table_a           |
+------+--------------+--------|
|  id  |    some_id   |  data  |
+------+--------------+--------|
|   1  |    111111    |    a   |
|   2  |    111111    |    a   |
|   3  |    222222    |    b   |
|   4  |    333333    |    c   |
|   5  |    333333    |    c   |
+------------------------------+
```

**Solve** (spring hibernate jpa hql):

```java
@Repository
public interface TableARepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<TableA, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<TableA> {
 
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("INSERT INTO TableA (someId,  data) " +
           "SELECT             :someId, :data " + //SELECT - is alias for INSERT ... VALUES 
           "FROM TableA " + // just rudiment HQL for INSERT
           "WHERE NOT EXISTS " +
           "          (SELECT 1 " +
           "          FROM TableA " +
           "          WHERE someId = :someId) " +
           "          GROUP BY someId" //derived table with one row
    )
    void saveIfNotExists(@Param("someId") Long someId,
                         @Param("data") String data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add "!" operator like this :

```
String hql = "INSERT INTO employee(emp_id, emp_name)"
        + " SELECT '100001' , 'John'  FROM employee "
        + " WHERE !EXISTS (SELECT 1 from employee WHERE emp_name  = 'John')";
```